# Can't export PDF using PDFTK in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, export, pdftk

I'm trying use PDFTK in Rails 4 to let users download a PDF by clicking a link in their browser. The form data is entered through the app and sent to the form fields using PDFTK. However, I'm not able to view the filled-out PDF when I visit the corresponding URL. Below is my relevant code.

Here is app/controllers/form_controllers.rb:

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController

def show
    @tables = Table.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
            pdf = TestPdfForm.new(@tables)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: "filled-form.pdf", type: 'application/pdf'
        end
    end
end

end
```

Here is app/pdfs/fillable_form_pdf.rb:

```
class FillablePdfForm

attr_writer :template_path
attr_reader :attributes

def initialize
  fill_out
end

def export(output_file_path=nil)
  output_path = output_file_path || "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdfs/#    {SecureRandom.uuid}.pdf" 
  pdftk.fill_form template_path, output_path, attributes
  output_path
end

def get_field_names 
  pdftk.get_field_names template_path
end

def template_path
  @template_path ||= "#{Rails.root}/lib/pdf_templates/test_form.pdf" 
end

protected

def attributes
  @attributes ||= {}
end

def fill(key, value)
  attributes[key.to_s] = value
end

def pdftk
  @pdftk ||= PdfForms.new(ENV['PDFTK_PATH'])
end

def fill_out
  raise 'Must be overridden by child class'
end

end


class TestPdfForm < FillablePdfForm

def initialize(tables)
 super()
 @tables = tables
 fill_out
end

protected

def fill_out

  fill :date, Date.today.to_s

  [:first_name, :last_name].each do |field|
  fill field, @tables.send(field)
end

fill :comments, "Hello, World"

end
end
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

I've since gotten my app to actually run the code associated with fillable_form_pdf. However, now there is an issue with verifying that Heroku knows exactly where the PDFTK binary is located.

I've set up the PDFTK_PATH environment variable to point to /vendor/pdftk/bin/pdftk, but I'm still getting an error that says:

"Cliver::Dependency::NotFound (Could not find an executable ["/vendor/pdftk/bin/pdftk"] on your path.)"

I have actually went through the steps to install the pdftk dependency on my Windows 7 machine, and there is definitely a pdftk file in that Heroku file path. So I'm not sure what I'm missing here, can anyone push me in the right direction?